# Can I get Google Ads from Google Custom Search API for requested query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-custom-search

I would like to get Google Ads for a specific search term using the Google Custom Search API. Getting search results works fine (see code below) using the GET-command but Ads are not included in the response I think.

Is there a way to get Ads from Google for a specific search term using the Custom Search API? Or maybe with another API?

I would be very thankful for help, thanks!

Code for getting search results:

```
function requestSearchResult() {
    jQuery.get("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1/", {
            q: SearchTerm,
            cx: "01042***5fgs",
            key: "AL***Xra",
        },
        function(items, status) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<a href=\"" + items.items[0].link + "\">" + items.items[0].htmlTitle + "</a>";
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + items.items[0].displayLink;
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + items.items[0].htmlSnippet;
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += "<br>" + '<img src="' + items.items[0].pagemap.cse_thumbnail[0].src + '" alt="text mode" />';
            ...
            ...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Custom Search API does not provide ads.

If you want search and ads consider using the Custom Search Element which does both: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

Or sign up for Custom Search Ads: https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/

Comment: What is the best way to realize the following work flow (search engine) using APIs?  
1. user enters search term in text box, e.g. in French  
2. get ads for the search term in French  
3. translate search term to English (Translation API)  
4. get search results (items) for translated search term (English)  
5. translate search results from English to French, to be translated: title, snippet  
6. visualize the results: ads in French (link ads with Google AdSense), translated search results (title translated to French, link, snippet translated to French, thumbnail)

Comment: You might be able to use the new Callbacks feature of the Search Element to call the Google Translate APIs
See https://customsearch.googleblog.com/2019/06/introducing-callbacks-for-even-more.html

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this may be done? I want ads data for a set of keywords (about 200 or so).